# How to view all file names that used to be in a folder?

Tags: git

It seems I somehow deleted some files in a folder, and I can't remember their names etc.

Is it possible to list all files that have ever been created in a given folder?

e.g.

```
/db/scripts/
```

I then want to view the file if I deleted it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git only knows about files that were committed, it doesn't keep track of random files. If the files were previously committed, AND you didn't commit the deletes, then simply typing `git status` will show you the files that are missing from the repo.

If you did commit the delete, you type `git log --name-status` to see which files have been modified when.

Once you find the commit, to view the file you can either do

```
git show [that revision]
```

to see the diff, or

```
git checkout [that revsion where file existed]
```

and view it howerver on the filesystem. Note that if you do the second command, you won't be on a branch anymore, so you will have to do `git checkout master` (or your previous branchname) to get back to your old state.

Comment: ok I see the file when I do git log --name-status, question, how can I search the entire output if it scrolls?  I tried '/' but not sure if thats searching just the visible page or everything?

Comment: / searches everything. Type n to go to the next match.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ git log --name-status --diff-filter=D | grep '^D\s'
D   arch/arm/configs/at91cap9adk_defconfig
D   arch/arm/configs/at91sam9260ek_defconfig
D   arch/arm/configs/at91sam9g20ek_defconfig
...
```

You might also want to include `R` (renamed) status.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you haven't committed your deletes, you can use `git ls-tree HEAD <folder name> -r`

If you have committed them, replace `HEAD` with the commit/tag/branch that has the files you want in it.